# Multiple frames in jFrame?

Tags: java, jframe, window, frame

I'm currently learning how to create a program with Java and jFrame. One problem I have is that I cant create new "forms" (how they are called in visualbasic) or windows. I'm using "Java-Editor", a usually very simple editor for things like that. Can anyone help me create a new form?
Thanks for your help in advance,
Till

Comment: Not sure what mean by form. Do you want to switch `JPanel`s within a `JFrame` ?

Answer (score 0):

From `JFrame` I assume that you are using Swing, and that you want multiple windows for your application. Your app should only use one `JFrame` object, if you need more windows (usually these are popup messages) then you can use dialogs. The class for this is `JOptionPane`.

Here is an example:

```
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"title","content",JOptionPane.INFORMATION_DIALOG);
```

As you can see you can control the title and the content displayed. Note that for the content parameter you can pass any `JPanel` object, so you dialog can display a lot of things.

The first parameter is the owner of the dialog, now I just set it to null, which means the dialog will have no owner. If you store a reference to your `JFrame` object then you can pass this for example and the dialog will always appear above your main window.

The last parameter is just for the general styling of the dialog. You can set it to other message types like `ERROR MESSAGE` too.

More info about displaying simple dialogs: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JOptionPane.html